# How to bring last Item of column to bottom

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am very new to flutter, Trying to design a login screen as in the image, I took a column and added all the widgets one by one. But coming to bottom part I tried with mainAxisAlignment, crossAxisAlignment still no luck, The bottom part is coming after the login button in the screen  i.e Don't have account? and Create Account.  I need those fields in bottom left to the screen.Please help how to achieve this.

```
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(150, 169, 62, 1),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Container(
              child: Image.asset('assets/logo_400.png'),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(60.0),
              width: 150.0,
              height: 150.0,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'Log into your account',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
          ),
          Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.phone,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        hintText: '10 digit mobile number',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        // enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                        //   // width: 0.0 produces a thin "hairline" border
                        //   borderSide: const BorderSide(
                        //       color: Colors.white, width: 0.0),
                        // ),
                        // border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                        suffixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.remove_red_eye,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.lock,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        hintText: 'Password',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        //color: Colors.blue,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        //disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                        //disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                        onPressed: () {
                          /*...*/
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          "Forgot Password",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 25,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                    child: ButtonTheme(
                      minWidth: 300.0,
                      height: 50.0,
                      buttonColor: Colors.white,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        //shape: StadiumBorder(),
                        onPressed: () {},
                        textColor: Colors.black,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'Login',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  //Spacer(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 150,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            "Don't have a account?",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
                          ),
                          FlatButton(
                            //color: Colors.blue,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            //disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                            //disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                            onPressed: () {
                              /*...*/
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              "Create Account",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              )),
        ],
      )),
);
```

[image]

Comment: Please share your code, we won't be able to help otherwise.

Comment: Some how by adding SizedBox, I am able to achieve this but, I'm not sure, what will be the correct approach.

Comment: and what are you trying to achieve? Center it all?

Comment: @kalpa could you provide us with a bit more information your question isn't very clear about what you are actually trying to achieve. Do you wish the create account to be centered at the bottom or do you want it above the login button or something else completely?

Comment: @JulienLachal  The bottom part is coming after the login button in the screen  i.e Don't have account? and Create Account.  I need those fields in bottom left to the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Don't have account? and Create Account. I need those fields in bottom
>   left to the screen

just change

```
Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end
```

to

```
Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start
```

[image: result]

BTW Have you tested this layout in landscape? You should wrap the entire form in a list view so that there is no overflow warnings.

Comment: Cool. Did the MainAxisAlignment.start work for you? I added an image of the result

Answer (score 4):

I know this is from a while ago.
But maybe it can help someone in the same spot.
The best solution to it is to wrap your widget Expanded and Align widgets As so :

```
Expanded(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Logout'),
                onTap: _logout,
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrapping Column in Row widget then after column children put your bottom part.